# Calendar like scheduling library java

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I am working on designing a scheduler exactly similar to calendar (outlook). Below are the main requirements

User should be able to schedule for below scenarios

- Daily
- Weekly (should be able to select the days of week/weekdays/weekend)
- Monthly (Should be able to select any day/s of month/ eg. 3rd Monday of the month)
- Yearly should be able to select month and day

Similar to below image

[image]

I have looked for the DB design which is very close to my requirement

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysschedules-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Also, have explored quartz. But with quartz, I don't have the facility to select relative days e.g. 3rd weekend of month.

Is there any java library which can provide the next schedule date based on configurations?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make a cron expression for the 3rd Saturday/Sunday of the month, so Quartz can be scheduled that way.

Here the expression for 3rd Saturday:

```
0 0 0 ? * 7#3 *
```

Here is cron converter that you can explore: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: If I want to select multiple weekdays , 3rd weekend (Sat and Sun) ?

Comment: Ah dont know if this is possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Spring class [CronTrigger](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.html) which could you configure with "linux-like" cron expression, which you could obtain from for example here [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/;jsessionid=node02ga50waleafcu8rewh0r2d0f27895.node0?0),

example of usage (every month on 3th Sunday):

`CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("0 0 12 ? 1/1 SUN#3 *");
taskScheduler.schedule(new RunnableTask("Cron Trigger"), cronTrigger);`

inspired by this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler#scheduling-with-crontrigger)

Comment: that does not support

Comment: could you be more specific what is not supported?

Comment: Spring cron does not support e.g. Last day of month. etc.